# Python - How do i use two frames in one gui?

Tags: python, tkinter

It shows a error when i try to use two frames at once, and i cannot add the frame i want.

I was trying to make a custom topbar and it kept showing me this error.

Code i am using:

```
self.mainframe = tk.Frame(master, width=30)
        self.mainframe.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        
        # Create the display widget
        self.display = tk.Entry(self.mainframe, width=30, justify='right')
        self.display.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, pady=5)

        # Create the buttons
        self.create_button("7", 1, 0)
        self.create_button("8", 1, 1)
        self.create_button("9", 1, 2)
        self.create_button("/", 1, 3)
        self.create_button("4", 2, 0)
        self.create_button("5", 2, 1)
        self.create_button("6", 2, 2)
        self.create_button("*", 2, 3)
        self.create_button("1", 3, 0)
        self.create_button("2", 3, 1)
        self.create_button("3", 3, 2)
        self.create_button("-", 3, 3)
        self.create_button("0", 4, 0)
        self.create_button(".", 4, 1)
        self.create_button("C", 4, 2)
        self.create_button("+", 4, 3)
        self.create_button("=", 5, 0, columnspan=4)
        
        self.topbar = tk.Frame(self.mainframe, width=60)
        self.topbar.pack() # Error: cannot use geometry manager pack inside .!frame which already has slaves managed by grid
```

Comment: `pack()` and `grid()` cannot be used together inside same container, i.e. for your case `self.mainframe`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that we cannot use grid and pack in the same frame, so for others:

```
frame1(master)
frame1.grid() # Yeah

frame2(master)
frame2.pack() # No
_________________
frame1(master)
frame1.grid() # Yeah

frame2(master)
frame2.grid() # Yeah

_________________
frame1(master)
frame1.grid() # Yeah

frame2(frame1)
frame2.pack() # Yeah
```